# Strange formatting of date in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ls, date, timestamps

I am working on a script to sort my downloads folder by the date the files were created. This is the script I am using:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Downloads
for FILENAME in *
do
    if [[ -f $FILENAME ]]; then
        date="$(ls -l $FILENAME | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | tr -d '.')"
        mkdir -vp "$date"
        find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name $FILENAME -exec mv {} "$date" \;
    fi
done
cd -
```

The name of the folder created by this script is just `Jun` which leads me to believe there is some sort of conversion going on somewhere.

If I do just a

```
ls -l test0 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | tr -d '.'
```

the date shows `19062014` correctly.

This is the result of a `bash -x` of the script:

```
sigurd@Goliath ~ -> bash -x clean
+ cd /home/sigurd/Downloads
+ for FILENAME in '*'
+ [[ -f test0 ]]
++ ls -l test0
++ tr -s ' '
++ cut -d ' ' -f 6
++ tr -d .
+ date=Jun
+ mkdir -vp Jun
mkdir: created directory 'Jun'
+ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name test0 -exec mv '{}' Jun ';'
+ for FILENAME in '*'
+ [[ -f test1 ]]
++ ls -l test1
++ tr -s ' '
++ cut -d ' ' -f 6
++ tr -d .
+ date=Jun
+ mkdir -vp Jun
+ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name test1 -exec mv '{}' Jun ';'
+ cd -
/home/sigurd
```

The functionality I'm looking for is that the script should move files into folders named `19_06_2014`, `20_06_2014` etc. based on when the file was created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wild guess: you have an alias for `ls` that's being used when you try the command interactively, and that alias isn't used in the script.  Something like this, perhaps?

```
alias ls="ls --full-time"
```

Note that conventional wisdom says that trying to parse `ls` is a bad idea.  Assuming you're on a Linux machine, something like this might be preferable:

```
stat "$FILENAME" | awk '/^Modify: /{print $2}'
```

EDIT: Or, as Stéphane points out below, using `find` with `-printf` is even better.  The output of `stat` is slightly easier to predict than `ls`, but `-printf` allows for an output format that's entirely controlled by you.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it would be easier to use awk, just wasn't quite comfortable as to how.

Comment: Parsing the output of `stat` like that is hardly any better. GNU `find` can print the modification time in any format you like with its `-printf`.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest using a date format like `2014-06-19`. That way a `ls` would show them in chronological order.

On a GNU system:

```
#! /bin/bash -
cd ~/Downloads &&
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%p\0%TF\0' |
    while IFS= read -rd '' file && read -d '' date; do
      mkdir -vp "$date" && mv "$file" "$date"
    done
```

With `zsh` on any system:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/stat || exit

cd ~/Downloads &&
  for file (./*(ND.)) {
    zstat -A date -F %F +mtime $file &&
      mkdir -p $date &&
      mv $file $date
  }
```

Comment: Hadn't thought about using `-printf` instead of `stat` - that's definitely an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete code

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Downloads
for FILENAME in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do    
    DATE=$(stat "$FILENAME" | awk '/^Modify: /{print $2}')
    [ ! -d "$DATE" ] && mkdir -vp "$DATE"

    mv "$FILENAME" "${DATE}/$FILENAME"
done
cd -
```

Comment: Note that GNU `find` (you're already using a GNUism with `-maxdepth`) can do `stat`'s job (and better) with `-printf` (`find` had `-printf` decades before GNU introduced its `stat` command). Using command substitution on the output of `find` means that it will break (possibly severely with security implications) on filenames contain blank or wildcard characters. You're not checking for succesful completion of `cd` or `mkdir`.